# How to print a collection item in static method?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Family> Families = new List<Family>();
        Family fam1 = new Family();
        fam1.Nickname = "Family One";
        fam1.FamilyId = 1;
        Adults father = new Adults();
        father.name = " Jim";
        fam1.father = father;
        Adults mother = new Adults();
        mother.name = "Amy";
        fam1.mother = mother;

        fam1.father.age = 34;
        fam1.mother.age = 33;
        fam1.father.job = "Programmer";
        fam1.mother.job = "Nurse";
        fam1.father.licNumber = 2344454;
        fam1.mother.licNumber = 88888;

        List<Person> Children = new List<Person>();

        Person Child1 = new Person();
        Child1.name = "Bob";
        Child1.age = 3;

        Children.Add(Child1);                    
        Families.Add(fam1);

        foreach (var family in Families)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
            Console.WriteLine("Parents : ");
            Console.WriteLine($"{fam1.father.name} - {fam1.father.job} - { fam1.father.licNumber}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{fam1.mother.name} - {fam1.mother.job} - {fam1.mother.licNumber}");
            Console.WriteLine("Kids");
            Console.WriteLine($"{Child1.name} - {Child1.age}");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm able to print this on console via `foreach`.

But, I'm trying to create a method that can take a parameter (`family` in this case) and print the family's information like I did in the `foreach` block.

```
PrintFamily(fam1);

private static void PrintFamily(Family family)
{
    //I'm stuck here
}
```

Comment: Move all your `Console.WriteLine()` into `PrintFamily()` and call it in `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private static void PrintFamily(Family family)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
     Console.WriteLine("Prents : ");
     Console.WriteLine($"{family.father.name} - {family.father.job} - { fam1.father.licNumber}");
     Console.WriteLine($"{family.mother.name} - {family.mother.job} - {family.mother.licNumber}");

    if(familiy.Children!=null && familiy.Children.Any())
    {

     Console.WriteLine("Kids");

        foreach{var child in family.Children}
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"{child .name} - {child .age}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want my method to take in "Family" type parameter.
Meaning, if I pass through in this case FAM1 , then I want this method to print all the FAM1's information

Comment: that what my sample does

Comment: oh ok so if you need to print the children then i can update

Comment: Wow John! It worked :) Thank you so much man! I spent like 2 hours on this, yet the solution is so simple :D I APPRECIATE IT :) WOW!

Comment: no problem - mark it as Answered if you're ok with it :-) good luck

Comment: i did this freehand so there might be a syntax error or 2 but you get the idea

Comment: John, again..thank you so much! I had a miserable day at work and you just made my day mate!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of things in your code that definitely need improving. You need to respect pascal case for your property names. Also, should prefer object initializers instead of partially instantiating your objects and then going inside their properties. It removes a lot of lines, and makes more sense as of what's been initialized and it's done in one place.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Family> Families = new List<Family>();
        Adults father = new Adults { Name = "Jim", Age = 34, Job = "Programmer", LicNumber = "2344454" };
        Adults father = new Adults { Name = "Amy", Age = 33, Job = "Nurse", LicNumber = "88888" };
        Family fam1 = new Family { Nickname = "Family One", FamilyId = 1, Father = father, Mother = mother };
    }

    private static void DisplayFamilyMemberInformation(Family familyMember)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
        Console.WriteLine("Prents : ");
        Console.WriteLine($"{fam1.father.name} - {fam1.father.job} - { fam1.father.licNumber}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{fam1.mother.name} - {fam1.mother.job} - {fam1.mother.licNumber}");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kevin,
I appreciate your input. I'm complete beginner and trying my best.  I will review your code and learn . Thank you so much again.

Comment: Kevin, are there any 1 or 2 tips you can give someone who is learning the basics of C#? I love how clean your code is. Thank you in advance~

Comment: Best way to improve is to keep going at it and go on GitHub, try to find some open source projects you can try to contribute to or start on your own. The more you practice your craft, the better you're going to become

Comment: I will practice my Code KAtas! OR in my case Code TULI ( Tuli = Katas, but in Korean ITF Taekwon-do)

Answer (score 0):

*"can you show me how to print child as well?"*

Alas.. same error Jeff Sessions made last May, at the Mexican border. If you define the Children like this, they will get lost !

You already defined a FamilyId. **Use FamilyId also in your person record**, like

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public int FamilyId; // THIS !
}
```

Make sure you connect the child to the family, like so

```
        Person Child1 = new Person();
        Child1.name = "Bob";
        Child1.age = 3;
        Child1.FamilyId = fam1.FamilyId; // THIS ! connect it
        Children.Add(Child1);
```

.. this will allow you to report the children, like

```
    static void Report(List<Family> Families, List<Person> children)
    {
        foreach (var family in Families)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{family.Nickname} ({family.FamilyId})");
            Console.WriteLine("Prents : ");
            Console.WriteLine($"{family.father.name} - {family.father.job} - { family.father.licNumber}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{family.mother.name} - {family.mother.job} - {family.mother.licNumber}");
            Console.WriteLine("Kids");
            foreach (Person child in children)
              if (child.FamilyId == family.FamilyId)
                 Console.WriteLine("Child: " + child.name);
         }
    }
```